# Plotly Dash App: Two interdependent components

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I am trying to create an app in which two components, in this case radio buttons and a dropdown, are dependent on each other. This means that when the radio buttons change, the dropdown needs to adjust and vice versa.

Having a one-way dependency is fairly simple, and each callback works fine individually. However, when including both, the app shows the "Error loading dependencies" in the browser.

```
import pandas
import sys
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import datetime
import numpy as np
import math

df = pandas.DataFrame(list(zip([1,2,3], ['a', 'b', 'c'])))

app = dash.Dash(__name__)
server = app.server

app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        html.P('Select:'),
        dcc.RadioItems(
            id='radio',
            options=[
                {'label': x, 'value': x} for x in df[0].unique()
            ],
            value=df[0].unique()[0],
        ),
        dcc.Dropdown(
            id='dropdown',
            options=[
                {'label': x, 'value': x} for x in df[1].unique()
            ],
            value=[df[1].unique()[0]]
        ),
    ])


@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output('dropdown', 'value'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input('radio', 'value')])

def update_dropdown(radio):
    return(df[df[0]==radio][1].values[0])

@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output('radio', 'value'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input('dropdown', 'value')])

def update_radio(dropdown):
    return(df[df[1]==dropdown][0].values[0])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=False)
```

Comment: Yep, it's strange... Try to solve it today but unsuccessfull. Maybe Dash don't allow this action, who knows